# Updating JTable after inline edit

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have 2 classes, one to make a frame and the other to handle and implement the interface TableModel. When editing cells inline and updating the values in the class that implements TableModel I then need to refresh the table to show the updated data (as the table needs to auto sort thus when I inline edit a cell the rows may need to be re-ordered). The problem I'm having is after updating the data I can't figure out how to refresh the table, I've tried a hacky way of refreshing it when you click off the cell or press enter but I feel there could be a more elegant solution, any ideas?

Comment: That's because I've only ever got 2 answers that work to the questions I've asked. :/

Answer (score 1):

The TableModel is responsible for invoking the fireTableCellChanged(...) method when data is changed in the model. Sorting will then happen automatically.

Read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on How to Use Tables for more information about TableModels and sorting.

I suggest you just use the DefaultTableModel so you don't have to worry about this since it implements all the TableModel methods.